# How to force ant print junit's report with colour

Tags: java, ant, junit

Below is my build.xml

```
    <target name="tdd" description="Run unittest" depends="jar">
    <mkdir dir="${build.test.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${build.test.dir}"
        includeAntRuntime="false">
        <classpath refid="lib.junit"/>
        <classpath refid="lib.dataquery"/>
    </javac>
    <jar destfile="${build.jar.dir}/dataqueryTDD.jar">
        <fileset dir="${build.test.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
    </jar>
    <mkdir dir="${build.test.report.dir}"/>

    <junit printsummary="yes">
        <classpath refid="lib.junit"/>
        <classpath refid="lib.dataquery"/>
        <classpath refid="lib.dataquery.tdd"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest todir="${build.test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java"/>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>

    <junitreport todir="${build.test.report.dir}" tofile="TEST-Summary.xml">
        <fileset dir="${build.test.report.dir}" includes="*.xml"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

I can run them and print reports without errors.

However, ant will only tell me if there is a failed test. I need to manually checkout the test report by command `cat`. I am wondering how to force ant dumping the failed test report(s) on stdout with colour.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<!-- new testwithcat target -->
<target name="testwithcat" depends="tdd, catreport"/>

<target name="tdd" description="Run unittest" depends="jar">
    <mkdir dir="${build.test.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${build.test.dir}"
        includeAntRuntime="false">
        <classpath refid="lib.junit"/>
        <classpath refid="lib.dataquery"/>
    </javac>
    <jar destfile="${build.jar.dir}/dataqueryTDD.jar">
        <fileset dir="${build.test.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
    </jar>
    <mkdir dir="${build.test.report.dir}"/>

<!-- add errorProperty, failureProperty to junit task -->
<junit printsummary="yes" errorProperty="test.failed" failureProperty="test.failed">
        <classpath refid="lib.junit"/>
        <classpath refid="lib.dataquery"/>
        <classpath refid="lib.dataquery.tdd"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest todir="${build.test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java"/>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>

    <junitreport todir="${build.test.report.dir}" tofile="TEST-Summary.xml">
        <fileset dir="${build.test.report.dir}" includes="*.xml"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>

<!-- add cat report target that runs if test.failed has been set in junit task -->  
  <target name="catreport" depends="test" if="test.failed">
    <echo message="Test failed - cat the test report"/>
    <!-- customise the following to cat your report in colour -->
    <exec executable="cat">
      <arg value="${build.test.report.dir}/TEST-Summary.xml"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
```

Run using:

```
ant testwithcat
```

Output:

```
Test failed - cat the test report
[content of ${build.test.report.dir}/TEST-Summary.xml]
```

You will need to customise

```
<exec executable="cat">
    <arg value="${build.test.report.dir}/TEST-Summary.xml"/>
</exec>
```

with your own command to "cat your report in colour".

To get plain text output take a look at [Ant JUnit Nice Output Formatter](http://shaman-sir.wikidot.com/one-liner-output-formatter).

You can use

```
<report format="frames" todir="${build.test.report.dir}"/>
```

or

```
<report format="noframes" todir="${build.test.report.dir}"/>
```

in the junitreport task to generate html output.

You can replace

```
<exec executable="cat">
    <arg value="${build.test.report.dir}/TEST-Summary.xml"/>
</exec>
```

with a call to display the html in a browser. See [Exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) for example code to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I can cat the report if there is a failed test. However, format of the ```TEST-Summary.xml``` is not a human friendly ... Are there any commands for parsing that XML ? Or, is it possible to get the failed test so that I can run another ```junit``` with ```printsummary``` off to dump those errors?

Comment: Both of the suggestions (The web page and the plain text one) are very nice. Personally, I pick the webpage one since it required lesser codes :D. Thanks again.

Comment: Comments added to answer.